# Alternate method to use mysql date_sub(now(),interval 1 day) in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Alternate method to use mysql `date_sub(now(),interval 1 day)` in php?

Actually I want this alternative because in zend where clause second parameter is `date_sub` function and it is taking it as string.  Below shows exact query

```
->where("FROM_UNIXTIME(qnas.cdate,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')>?" ,"date_sub(now(),interval 1 day)");
```

second parameter `date_sub(now(),interval 1 day)` is mysql function to show record greater than previous day date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
->where("FROM_UNIXTIME(qnas.cdate,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 day)");
```

If the value is not a user supplied parameter, there's no point in trying to bind it like one. Just write it into the query. Also, if your `cdate` column is any sort of date/time column, you don't need the `FROM_UNIXTIME` conversion.